# Junk characters when file is read from SD Card in android

Tags: java, android, file

I have a file in my sdcard named **file.txt** containing the text "hello android". I am trying to read this file using the code given below

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

File file = new File(sdcard, "file.txt");

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

 try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
            builder.append('\n');
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: text : " + builder.toString());
```

This code is working fine but I am getting a lot of junk characters with the text. I tried to look for it but couldn't find anything relevant. Can anyone help here?

I am also attaching a pic of my output.

[image: output]

Comment: What character encoding was the original file written in?

Comment: UTF-8 i guess, I created that file using sublime text editor in my computer and transferred it to my phone.

Comment: Weird, text is appearing fine when I am displaying the same in a toast message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the file is not UTF-8.

*"Any characters not representable in the 8-bit character set will come through as question marks."* -> UTF-8

Try write something from the app to this file using UTF-8, then query it back and see if it displays ok.

Comment: Can you help me on how can we determine the encoding of a file?

Comment: Character encoding was the problem. thanks for helping.

Comment: There is a good tool for this: https://code.google.com/archive/p/juniversalchardet/ 

What happens if you: String testString = "testtest" (no spaces); and .append(testString). Does it display ok in both toast and console?

Comment: yes it was working well in toast before too, now it started working in console also.